# Mary TTS with HTML/JavaScript and PHP

Tags: text-to-speech, speech-synthesis, marytts

I installed Mary TTS (version 5.1.2) on my Windows (and Linux computers).
I started the Mary TTS server and the Mary TTS client, and I did some trials with text to audio conversion in the GUI window (its great).

I would like to use Mary TTS on my website to read text aloud, where a user can add a text into the input field and generate the output like in the GUI window, without using the java client.

For example:

```
<input type="text" id="text">
<button onclick="play('text');">Speak it</button>

<script>
function play(id){
    var text = document.getElementById(id).value;
    var a = new Audio(text);
        a.play();
    }
</script>
```

Just to get started.. I can't realize how to do that in HTML/JavaScript and PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Step 1. Host MaryTTS on a server

I wrote [marytts-http](https://github.com/draffensperger/marytts-http) to wraps MaryTTS so it's easy to deploy to Heroku, though you could deploy it to other servers as well.

First you'll need an account with Heroku, then install their [toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/) and run `heroku login`.

After that you can deploy `marytts-http` to Heroku like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/draffensperger/marytts-http
cd marytts-http
heroku create
git push heroku master
```

## Step 2. Use your hosted MaryTTS instance in your website

Heroku will give a name to your `marytts-http` instance that you created above which you can change later on the Heroku dashboard. Let's say the name of your instance is `my-marytts`, then the URL to get a text-to-speech audio file would be `my-marytts.herokuapp.com/?text=Hello` (just specify the `text` query parameter).

To embed the audio on your website you should use an `<audio>` tag, e.g.:

```
<audio src="my-marytts.herokuapp.com/?text=Hello" autoplay></audio>
```

The `autoplay` makes it start the audio when the element is loaded. So in your case, what you could do is dynamically add an `<audio>` element after the user clicks the button, e.g.:

```
<input type="text" id="text">
<button onclick="play('text');">Speak it</button>

<span id="audio-container" style="display:none;"></span>

<script>
function play(id) {
  var maryttsHost = 'https://example-mary-tts.herokuapp.com'
  var text = document.getElementById(id).value;
  var container = document.getElementById("audio-container");
  var audioSrc = maryttsHost + '/?text=' + encodeURIComponent(text);
  container.innerHTML = '<audio src="' + audioSrc + '" autoplay></audio>';
}
</script>
```

You would need to change `maryttsHost` above to match the actual URL of your `marytts-http` instance on Heroku.

Comment: Thank you for the link. On the 'README.md' page you mentioned: "Here's sample PHP code for signing a request and embedding it in a page:", .. but I could find any PHP code. Please advise on that. Thx.

Comment: I'll fix the README soon, but in the mean time here's a link to PHP code where I use it: https://github.com/draffensperger/memorizer/blob/66dafdbaaf6702254f6651ea575c62a05f74d1c3/public/mary_embed.php